# Use quantifiers and logical connectives to express the fact that a quadratic polynomial with real number coefficients has at most two real roots.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic

"Use quantifiers and logical connectives to express the fact
that a quadratic polynomial with real number coefficients
has at most two real roots."

**My solution:**
1. ∀a∀b∀c [ 
2. ∀x [(ax2 + bx + c = 0)⟶∃w∃z(aw2 + bw + c = 0 ⋀ az2 + bz + c = 0 ⋀ (x = w V x = z))] 
3. V
 4. ㄱ∃x [ax2 + bx + c = 0]]

**My thought process:**
1. For all triplet real nums a, b and c,
either:
2. For all real numbers x, if ax2 + bx + c = 0, then there are at least one and utmost two real nums w and z that x is equal to. (hence didn't give w != z)
3. or:
 4. there is no real number that satisfies the condition ax2 + bx + c = 0. (handling the zero roots possible condition)
Edit: The domain of discourse of all variables is the set of real numbers.

Please correct me if the answer is wrong. If by any chance it is right, maybe I can shorten it in some way or there is a better solution?

Comment: I would rather have gone with "If there are three numbers that all are roots, then some of them must be equal".

Comment: Then what about zero roots? Should I add it to ur proposed solution with a disjunction as I did with mine?

Comment: Not a problem. "If there are three real numbers $r,s,t$ that fulfill $x^2+1=0$, then some of those the must be equal" makes complete sense, and is entirely true.

Comment: Got it! Left side of implication was made false so the solution automatically becomes true. Thanks.

Comment: Also, don't forget to specify $a\neq0$, since we are supposed to be dealing with a quadratic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all real $a,b,c,x,y,z$, if
$$(ax^2 + bx + c)^2 + (ay^2 + by + c)^2 + (az^2 + bz + c)^2 = 0,$$ 
then $x = y$ or $y = z$ or $z = x$.

Comment: Makes sense to me.

Comment: You need to put in $a \neq 0$ like J.-E. Pin's answer. Or else I think your answer is wrong. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation

Answer (score 1):

$$\forall x \ \forall y\ \forall z\ \forall a\ \forall b\ \forall c\ \bigl({a ≠ 0} \wedge {(ax^2 + bx + c = ay^2 + by + c = az^2 + bz + c = 0)\bigr) \rightarrow \bigl((x = y) \vee (y = z) \vee (z = x)\bigr) }$$

Answer (score 0):

You have missed several points in your solution. First of all you did not specify that the coefficients are real. You also assumed that every quadratic equation has at least one real root. Why there is no real number that satisfies the condition ax2 + bx + c = 0 ? Over all your solution looks correct.

Comment: The natural context indicated in the question is that the domain of discourse is the set of reals, in which case one would not further specify that the coefficients are reals. That is, quantifiers are automatically assumed to range over $\mathbb R $.

Comment: Thanks, that makes it easier.

Comment: Sorry mate, I forgot to mention the DOD which is the set of all real numbers.

Comment: No problem. Have a good time.